# Cannot initialize the datasource object of ole db provider msolap for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, windows, reporting-services, ssas

I have seen a few posts that might be considered similar but nothing seems to be my exact problem. We recently acquired a new server that will act as our new database server.

The problem I am encountering is that once we moved and I set everything up on the new SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition our reports no longer work when I say no longer work I mean that they do not return any data from the cube on the server if I run the reports from my project and point them to the old server with the exact same data on I get results change the ip to new server and report return nothing.

What makes this problem even stranger is that it seems to only be for reports that use our Cube in SSAS which I moved to the new server as well.

The Cube processes perfectly on the new server. I have set up a linked server as well which also works perfectly I can execute cube related queries from SQL Browser but the moment I attempt to run a report pointing to that same stored procedure I get the error mentioned above. The reports also return no data then running from the URL `http:\\localhost\reports` .

I am sure this must be some setup or something that I missed any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue? You need to open TCP port 2383 on the server for the default instance of Analysis Services. See MSDN > Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow Analysis Services Access: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174937.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that lucky I had already set up those firewall rules , I should probably also mention that my database, SSRS and SSAS are all running on the same server.

Comment: How about permissions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by permisions

Answer (score 0):

In Reporting Services you have a data source which connects to the Analysis Services cube? Is the data source using a credential that has permission to access the Analysis Services cube in the new server?

Comment: From reporting services I have a data source that connects to the database, the Cube is called from the stored procedures in the database , never directly and the sql user I use has full permission in the server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add a comment, not an answer! I'll leave it now you've commented.

Comment: You need to isolate the problem. Some suggestions: (1) What happens if you execute the stored procedure using SSMS on the server? (The stored procedure that SSAS data source is calling.) (2) What does SQL Server Profiler tell you? (3) Can you build a simplest possible report and get that to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: As I explained in the original post when executing the stored procedure from ssms using the same credentials as the reporting services it works, I have created a simple open row set procedure purely for testing this bug. And get the same error even when trying to execute that Stored procedure  from the  report builder.

Comment: Your original post is not at all clear. You need to do some more work yourself to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I discovered the error, should any one encounter this I merely had to add NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER to the Cube's Role as another member and Viola